# Position a <nav> at the bottom of a <div>

Tags: .net, html, nav

Can someone please explain to me how to move a  at the bottom of a ! I can't believe I'm struggling with something I believed would have been simple task.

I'm using the mvc template (html5) provided in .net and here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left" style="border: 2px solid red">
                <p class="site-title">
                    @Html.ActionLink("My website", "Index", "Home")
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="float-right" style="border: 2px solid red;">
                <section id="login">
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                </section>
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p>
                    &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - MyWebsite.com</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

While not displayed in the code above, the height of my div will be 101px and I want the navigation menu to be displayed at the bottom of the right inside div but I've tried playing around with various settings in the site.css and using inline style and as I said, I can't get it to display where I want it to! I'm still googling, but hopefully someone will have solution for me. I've spent way too much time on this!

Thanks.

Comment: what u want to move..i dnt understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this one:
working Example : http://jsfiddle.net/YNBxz/792/

First, I have given the div's position as relative. Then I have floated the nav to the right,gave position as absolute and bottom:0,right:0.

HTML:

```
<div id ="div1" >
        Here is a div with height 101px

        <nav>
           <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a> |
           <a href="http://www.bing.com/">Bing</a>
        </nav>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
   position:relative;
   height:101px;
   width:100%;
   border:2px solid black;
}


#div1 nav {


float:right;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;

}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. jsfidlle does not appear to work in IE and when I try it chrome, it does not do what I want. Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly but I basically want the navigation to be displayed horizontally but at the bottom of the div it is contained within. I've managed to achive what I wanted by introducing a table but I don't know if this is good practise or not. I would have hoped to achieve this without using a table.

Comment: Oops! I'm back!! This worked perfectly! Thanks. It somehow used the wrong code when I clicked on your link... Weird.. Anyway, I've just tried your code directly in .net and it worked immediately in both Chrome and IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border: 2px solid red;float:right;">
           <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>about</li>
                    <li>contact</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YNBxz/792/

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but I think I did not explain myself correctly. I want to move the navigation (which is layed out horizontally) to the bottom of the div within which is it contained.

Comment: Let's try this again with a link this time. I've uploaded a snapshot which hopefully will clarify what I'm trying to achieve. Check [snapshot](http://www.mansfieldart.com/nav1.png)